# Changing header of Questionnaire sdaps

Tags: pdftex, header-footer, document-classes

I am new to sdaps and I want edit below header, which was auto generated by sdaps. I was unable to edit this use using latex.

[image]

I want Add description along with index number like this in to the header.

[image]

I hope you Understand what I say

This is my code.

```
\documentclass[english,pdf]{sdaps}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\author{Menuka Ishan}
\title{My Title }

\begin{document}
    \begin{questionnaire}

        \begin{choicegroup}{Please write your student ID into the $\sqcup$
and check the corresponding cross.\\ }
       \groupaddchoice{\Huge$\Box$}
       \groupaddchoice{\Huge$\Box$}
       \groupaddchoice{\Huge$\Box$}
       \groupaddchoice{\Huge$\Box$}
       \groupaddchoice{\Huge$\Box$}
       \groupaddchoice{\Huge$\Box$}
       \groupaddchoice{\Huge$\Box$}
       \groupaddchoice{\Huge$\Box$}

       \choiceline{\hfill 0}
       \choiceline{\hfill 1}
       \choiceline{\hfill 2}
       \choiceline{\hfill 3}
       \choiceline{\hfill 4}
       \choiceline{\hfill 5}
       \choiceline{\hfill 6}
       \choiceline{\hfill 7}
       \choiceline{\hfill 8}
       \choiceline{\hfill 9}


     \end{choicegroup}
    \end{questionnaire}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you post the code so that we need not recreate the entire play?

Comment: Since I was new to SDAPS I just create index field (above photo) only. Now I'm trying to add index with description. Is it alright if I paste the that code?

Comment: Since not everybody has `sdaps` installed: Here's a download link: http://sdaps.org/releases/sdaps-1.1.10.tar.gz

Comment: Christian download link is not enough,
You have to fulfill dependencies too.
 http://sdaps.org/Documentation/Dependencies

Comment: @MenukaIshan: I meant for the `.tex` related stuff, not the software itself. The `sdaps.cls` etc. isn't available on CTAN or on TeXLive

Comment: @Christian My mistake. I misunderstood. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: @MenukaIshan: If I understand your question correctly, you want to replace the current `infotext` header etc. with the version from the snapshot, i.e. `This questionnaire is autogenerated...` etc?

Comment: @Christian yes I want to remove the auto generated text and Add index number marking along with My description. I can't find where to look? :(

Comment: @Christian If you can change the content of infotext header let me know please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not easy to understand this from the beginning.

The header is done with `\begin{info}...\end{info}`, which is in turn defined in `sdaps.cls` file, being used in the definition of `questionnaire`. It uses `\translate{infotext}` etc. strings.

Those strings are defined in `beamer` - translator - dictionary which aren't provided directly, unless the whole bunch of the software is installed, built and the dictionaries are created then.

Here is the `translate-sdaps-dictionary-English.dict` if this isn't available so far:

```
% This file is auto-generated from gettext translations (.po files).
% The header of the original file follows for reference:
%
% Translations for sdaps LaTeX classes.
% Copyright 2010-2013 Ferdinand Schwenk (ferdisdot@gmail.com).
% Copyright 2011-2013 Benjamin Berg (benjamin@sipsolutions.net).
%
% This work may be distributed and/or modified under the
% conditions of the LaTeX Project Public License, either version 1.3c
% of this license or (at your option) any later version.
% The latest version of this license is in
%   http://www.latex-project.org/lppl.txt
%

    \ProvidesDictionary{translator-sdaps-dictionary}{English}

    \providetranslation{infotext}{This questionnaire is automatically read by a computer program. Please use a pen for filling in your answers.}
    \providetranslation{standard-deviation}{Standard-Deviation}
    \providetranslation{info-cross}{Check}
    \providetranslation{info-correct}{Uncheck to correct}
    \providetranslation{answers}{Answers}
    \providetranslation{questionnaireid}{Questionnaire-ID:}
    \providetranslation{surveyid}{Survey-ID:}
    \providetranslation{draft}{draft}
    \providetranslation{info-select}{You can check any number of boxes in selection questions.}
    \providetranslation{info-mark}{For questions with a range (1--\arabic{markcheckboxcount}) choose the answer the mark that fits best.}
    \providetranslation{mean}{Mean}
```

Now the header - info - box:

```
  \begin{info}
    \translate{infotext}\\
    \if@checkmode@checkcorrect
      \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{llcX}
          \translate{info-cross}: & \checkedbox &\quad & \translate{info-select} \\
          \translate{info-correct}: & \correctedbox & & \translate{info-mark} \\
      \end{tabularx}
    \else
      \PackageError{sdaps}{Sorry, there is no help text for the checkmode you have choosen right now! Please pass the noinfo optional argument to the questionnaire environment!}\@ehb %
    \fi
  \end{info}
```

Basically you need the translations of `infotext`, `info-cross`, `info-select`, `info-mark` and `info-correct`.

If any of the predefined translations do not work, use

`\renewtranslation[⟨options⟩]{⟨key⟩}{⟨translation⟩}`

where `key` is the text to be changed, say, `infotext`. For the options see the `beamer` manual please.

---

```
\documentclass[english]{sdaps}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\author{Menuka Ishan}
\title{My Title }


\begin{document}

    \begin{questionnaire}
      \setcounter{section}{1}  % questionnaire sets this to zero internally without this

        \begin{choicegroup}{Please write your student ID into the $\sqcup$
and check the corresponding cross.\\ }
       \groupaddchoice{\Huge$\Box$}
       \groupaddchoice{\Huge$\Box$}
       \groupaddchoice{\Huge$\Box$}
       \groupaddchoice{\Huge$\Box$}
       \groupaddchoice{\Huge$\Box$}
       \groupaddchoice{\Huge$\Box$}
       \groupaddchoice{\Huge$\Box$}
       \groupaddchoice{\Huge$\Box$}

       \choiceline{\hfill 0}
       \choiceline{\hfill 1}
       \choiceline{\hfill 2}
       \choiceline{\hfill 3}
       \choiceline{\hfill 4}
       \choiceline{\hfill 5}
       \choiceline{\hfill 6}
       \choiceline{\hfill 7}
       \choiceline{\hfill 8}
       \choiceline{\hfill 9}


     \end{choicegroup}
    \end{questionnaire}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for time Christian but while I using your knowledge to achieve my goal, new problems arise. Here is the link(http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/266878/remove-header-and-add-custom-header-to-sdaps-latex) . If you have bit of free time please help me :)

Answer (score 1):

Well actually I found out a partial solution to your problem:

Just redefining the translations for the language you're using in the document. Ie:

```
\deftranslation[to=Spanish]{infotext}{El cuestionario se lee automáticamente por un programa computerizado.  Por favor, utilice un bolígrafo para completar sus respuestas.}
\deftranslation[to=Spanish]{info-multi}{Selección múltiple}
\deftranslation[to=Spanish]{info-single}{Selección única}
\deftranslation[to=Spanish]{info-cross}{Seleccionado}
\deftranslation[to=Spanish]{info-corrected}{Deshacer selección}
```

**Note: The options passed to \renewtranslation and \deftranslation correspond to the [Translations package](https://ctan.math.illinois.edu/macros/latex/contrib/translations/translations_en.pdf)**

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Can you please make your code snippet -- as usual here -- compilable and add an screenshot of your result to your answer?