# Remove header and Add Custom header to SDAPS latex

Tags: header-footer

I'm using [sdaps-1.1.10.tar.gz](http://sdaps.org/releases/sdaps-1.1.10.tar.gz) (development snapshot) I was trying to design my own header in latex for SDAPS which has text along side with index number box like this

[image]

Instead of this auto generated this header.

[image]

My first intention was to edit current header as I found out [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/266611/changing-header-of-questionnaire-sdaps)

As it says I must edit **translate-sdaps-dictionary-English.dict** to edit the header. It's true but I was unable to generate expected out come because though what ever I do, if I put choicegroup middle of that it show above the auto generated header. This is the content of **translate-sdaps-dictionary-English.dict**

```
% This file is auto-generated from gettext translations (.po files).
% The header of the original file follows for reference:
%
% Translations for sdaps LaTeX classes.
% Copyright 2010-2013 Ferdinand Schwenk (ferdisdot@gmail.com).
% Copyright 2011-2013 Benjamin Berg (benjamin@sipsolutions.net).
%
% This work may be distributed and/or modified under the
% conditions of the LaTeX Project Public License, either version 1.3c
% of this license or (at your option) any later version.
% The latest version of this license is in
%   http://www.latex-project.org/lppl.txt
%

\ProvidesDictionary{translator-sdaps-dictionary}{English}

\providetranslation{infotext}{This is my header option hari yan mage deyiyo}
\providetranslation{standard-deviation}{Standard-Deviation}
\providetranslation{info-cross}{Check}
\providetranslation{info-correct}{Uncheck to correct}
\providetranslation{answers}{Answers}
\providetranslation{questionnaireid}{Questionnaire-ID:}
\providetranslation{surveyid}{Survey-ID:}
\providetranslation{draft}{draft}
\providetranslation{info-select}{You can check any number of boxes in selection questions.}
\providetranslation{info-mark}{For questions with a range (1--\arabic{markcheckboxcount}) choose the answer the mark that fits best.}
\providetranslation{mean}{Mean}
```

After few trials I couldn't create what I want so I tried to remove header and create a new one using latex but although I remove all the commands Header was not completely remove. Here is my content of **translate-sdaps-dictionary-English.dict** now

```
% This file is auto-generated from gettext translations (.po files).
% The header of the original file follows for reference:
%
% Translations for sdaps LaTeX classes.
% Copyright 2010-2013 Ferdinand Schwenk (ferdisdot@gmail.com).
% Copyright 2011-2013 Benjamin Berg (benjamin@sipsolutions.net).
%
% This work may be distributed and/or modified under the
% conditions of the LaTeX Project Public License, either version 1.3c
% of this license or (at your option) any later version.
% The latest version of this license is in
%   http://www.latex-project.org/lppl.txt
%
```

But output is this.

[image]

I was unable to remove those text on the header.
If anyone can help me removing the header or Creating My header will very helpful to me. This is my current latex code.

```
\documentclass[english,pdf]{sdaps}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\author{Menuka Ishan}
\title{The Title hode}

\begin{document}
    \begin{questionnaire}

        \begin{choicegroup}{Please write your student ID into the $\sqcup$
and check the corresponding cross.\\ }
       \groupaddchoice{\Huge$\Box$}
       \groupaddchoice{\Huge$\Box$}
       \groupaddchoice{\Huge$\Box$}
       \groupaddchoice{\Huge$\Box$}
       \groupaddchoice{\Huge$\Box$}
       \groupaddchoice{\Huge$\Box$}
       \groupaddchoice{\Huge$\Box$}
       \groupaddchoice{\Huge$\Box$}

       \choiceline{\hfill 0}
       \choiceline{\hfill 1}
       \choiceline{\hfill 2}
       \choiceline{\hfill 3}
       \choiceline{\hfill 4}
       \choiceline{\hfill 5}
       \choiceline{\hfill 6}
       \choiceline{\hfill 7}
       \choiceline{\hfill 8}
       \choiceline{\hfill 9}


     \end{choicegroup}
    \end{questionnaire}
\end{document}
```

Comment: No, I did not say that have to edit the dictionary file

Comment: @Christian Actually I want to edit it but it won't responding as I wanted, so I tried to remove header and add my header instead, but as you see it didn't well :(

Comment: Check `sdaps.cls`